# C# ASP.NET Need some idea on how to turn this hardcoded HTML Item boxes into Item info that I can took from the DB

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am creating a website that looks like eBay and I got some HTML template which I think I can use to integrate into the ASPX

However, I needed some help with this part,
If you look at the picture, you can see there are four boxes that include item
[image]

This is the html code

```
<div class="ltabs-item product-layout">
    <div class="product-item-container">
        <div class="left-block">
            <div class="product-image-container second_img ">
                <img src="image/demo/shop/resize/J5-270x270.jpg" alt="Apple Cinema 30&quot;" class="img-responsive" />
                <img src="image/demo/shop/resize/J9-270x270.jpg" alt="Apple Cinema 30&quot;" class="img_0 img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <!--Sale Label-->
            <span class="label label-sale">-15%</span>

            <!--full quick view block-->
            <a class="quickview iframe-link visible-lg" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="quickview.html">Quickview</a>
            <!--end full quick view block-->
        </div>
        <div class="right-block">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4><a href="product.html">Cupim Bris</a></h4>
                <div class="ratings">
                    <div class="rating-box">
                        <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="price">
                    <span class="price-new">$50.00</span>
                    <span class="price-old">$62.00</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="button-group">
                <button class="addToCart" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to Cart" onclick="cart.add('42', '1');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span class="">Add to Cart</span></button>
                <button class="wishlist" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to Wish List" onclick="wishlist.add('42');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
                <button class="compare" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Compare this Product" onclick="compare.add('42');"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- right block -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically when you look at the code, everything is hard coded, what I wanted to do is that every time the page loads, the item info will be taken from the DB and code-behind will supply the information then parse into that field.

How should I do that?

Comment: Do you have knowledge about aspnet? Because it seems to me that you have not. SO isn't a code writing service. First try yourself and if you are stuck you can ask a separate question. Start by looking into a `Repeater` or `DataList` Control and how to fill them with content from a Database. There are a lot of tutorials out there.

Comment: @VDWWD Hi, yes I do have little knowledge about ASPNET, what I did previously is to use DataList then put some css class into the DataList. I will look into Repeater, is there other method?

Comment: There are a lot of options. But start by using a Repeater and work from there.

Comment: @VDWWD How about ListView?
Is it good compare to Repeater or DataList?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into this tutorial. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/

Answer (score 0):

To show your c# page with dynamic content,you should update your static HTML page with scripting language to get data from database and update UI

AngularJS is one of the Java script framework to create page with dynamic content

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are developing with ASP.NET Web Forms as you mention ASPX files. If that is the case then you can use the `runat = "server'` attribute for the desired HTML elements. This way you can interact with them from your backend code. More on [ASP.NET Web Forms](https://www.asp.net/web-forms) and on [HTML Server Controls and runat = "server" attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478973.aspx)